# Error uploading file from form-data to Spring Server

Tags: spring-mvc, encode, multipart, form-data

I am uploading a picture using `form-data` taking the picture from the Client's PC to Spring MVC Server.

Update Page:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html >
> <html>
> <head>
> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
> <title>Spring MVC - Upload File</title>
> </head>
> <body>
> <form id="form1" method="post" action="/upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
> <!-- File input -->     
> <input name="file" id="file" type="file" /><br/>
> <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
> </form>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

And this is the **Spring Controller**

> ```
>  @RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
>  public @ResponseBody
>  String provaUpdate(MultipartHttpServletRequest request,Principal p,HttpServletResponse response)throws IOException {
>  String result="";
>  LocalFileManager mLocalFileManager = LocalFileManager.get();
>  Iterator<String> iterator = request.getFileNames();
>      while(iterator.hasNext())
>      {
>          System.out.println("iterator.next()="+iterator.next());
>      }
>          System.out.println("request.getFileMap().isEmpty()??"+request.getFileMap().isEmpty());
>        //  mLocalFileManager.saveLocalData(g,g.getPicturesCount(), request.getFile("new").getInputStream());
>     return result;
>  }
> ```

So, when i run that, it just prints:

> `request.getFileMap().isEmpty()??true`

Then, no Files seems to be uploaded, but if I get the `request.getInputStream()` I can write a TXT File showing that:

> ```
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryWG8vA5PuTFFxPBqK
> Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="1.jpg"
> Content-Type: image/jpeg
> �� JFIF      ��ICC_PROFILE   蠠     mntrRGB XYZ ٠   $ acsp                             ��    ӭ    )B9
>                                desc  D   ybXYZ     bTRC  Ԡ dmdd     ࠠ ɧXYZ  
> h   gTRC  Ԡ lumi  
> |   meas  
>  //(Symbols)  Long ETC, so the picture is sent !!
> ------WebKitFormBoundaryWG8vA5PuTFFxPBqK--
> ```

So, seems that the picture is sent correctly but the `MultipartHttpServletRequest` is not able to get the File.

Which is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake was that i am working with Thymeleaf, so the form is different.

It is solved changing that:

1- Create a class that contains a MultipartFile, like this:

> ```
> public class Images {
> MultipartFile image;
> public MultipartFile getImage() {
> return image;
> }
> public void setImage(MultipartFile image) {
> this.image = image;
> }
> }
> ```

2- The correct form code for a Spring Server working with Thymeleaf:

> ```
> <form id="myform"  action="#"  th:action="@{/upload}" th:object="${Images}"     method="POST" modelAttribute="Images"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
> <input type="file"   th:field="${Images.image}"  name="file"/>
> <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
> </form>
> ```

And finally the correct Controller method:

> ```
> @RequestMapping(value = "upload", method = RequestMethod.POST)
> public String addVocabularyValadate( @ModelAttribute("Images") Images images,BindingResult bindingResult,
>                     Model model) throws IOException 
> {
> System.out.println("inputstream Nombre!"+images.getImage().getOriginalFilename());
> if(bindingResult.hasFieldErrors() == true)
> return "error";
> else
> return "upload OK!";
> }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think,you may be missing below entry in your `spring configuration xml` file.

```
   <bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- below properties can be configured as per your need -->
        <property name="maxUploadSize" value="5000000" />
        <property name="maxInMemorySize" value="5000000" />
  </bean>
```

Comment: I am configurating my server as Java Application, so i configured this part like this:

`@Bean
        public MultipartConfigElement multipartConfigElement()     {
        MultiPartConfigFactory factory = new MultiPartConfigFactory();
        factory.setMaxFileSize("256KB");
        factory.setMaxRequestSize("256KB");
        return factory.createMultipartConfig();
   }`